# DropDownList not Updating to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I have three Drop Down Lists being populated, two from DB and another from an XML file. The problem is that I am losing the selected values in the submit method where I am trying to update the database with values from these drop downs. Here's the markup and code for one of the DDL's using the DB:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="deptsDDL">Department *</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="deptsDDL" class="form-control" placeholder="Department"
            runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="deptReqVal" runat="server"  
            ControlToValidate="deptsDDL" CssClass="text-danger" 
            InitialValue="Choose Department" 
            Display="Dynamic">* Select Department</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>
</div>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        deptsDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem("Choose Department", "Choose Department"));
        using (IDataReader deptReader = SiteDALC.GetDepartments())
        {
            while (deptReader.Read())
            {
                deptsDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(deptReader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                    deptReader.GetValue(0).ToString()));
            }
            var accountDept = SCWebUser.Current.ADProfile.Department;
            if (deptsDDL.Items.FindByText(accountDept) != null)
                deptsDDL.SelectedIndex = 
                    deptsDDL.Items.IndexOf(deptsDDL.Items.FindByText(accountDept));
        }
    }
}

protected void RegisterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        SiteDALC.UpdateRegistration(
            SCWebUser.Current.ADProfile.Username,
            inputFirstName.Text.Trim(),
            inputLastName.Text.Trim(),
            "530" + phone1.Text.Trim() + phone2.Text.Trim(),
            inputExtension.Text.Trim(),
            faxNum,
            cellNum,
            titleDDL.SelectedValue,
            addressDDL.SelectedValue,
            city.Text.Trim(),
            "CA",
            zip.Text.Trim(),
            deptsDDL.SelectedValue,
            DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly seeing the problem but suspect that I don't have a grasp of the DataTextDield and DataValueField properties.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: Can you include the code on postback where you are trying to access the values (the point where they are coming back empty)?

Comment: I've just added it Mike - they are coming back empty at this point in the debugger.

Comment: And when the page renders, are the DDLs populated or empty? Is the item you selected still selected?

Comment: They populate just fine on Page Load with the correct item selected, but are lost on the postback

Comment: Sorry I meant when it renders on postback. What is on the page? I would expect that (abnormally) the ddl would be empty.

Comment: It is empty. At least it was last time I disabled try/catches and my default error page. In fact, all three were coming up empty on the postback.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't really make sense. The only time I've had to populate controls on postback is for some 3rd party controls (I think Telerik). Something odd is going on.

Comment: is enableviewstate=true?

Comment: No wazz, I double-checked and it is not enabled - all other controls passing their values back. I think I'm not setting DataTextField and DataValueField properties correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the following in my Web.config file:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" enableViewState="false">
    ...
</pages>
```

I have no idea how this got there but obviously ViewState was disabled at site level.

## facepalm